# app crashes on image capture

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am capturing images through camera. Then I move to next controller where I display the captured image. I go back to capture image screen and this cycle continues for 10 to 15 times. After this when I try to capture the image the app crashes by giving "low memory warning".
Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) takePhoto:(id) sender
{
    /*
    tempControl *intermediate=[[tempControl alloc] initWithNibName:@"tempControl" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:intermediate animated:YES];
    [intermediate release];
     */
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [imagePickerController setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil]];
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Alert" message:@"Device Lacks Camera" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert = nil;
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [picker release];
    picker =nil;
    /*
    cropReciept *recieptToCrop=[[cropReciept alloc] initWithNibName:@"cropReciept" bundle:nil];
    [recieptToCrop setReciept:image];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recieptToCrop animated:YES];
    [recieptToCrop release];
     */
    OCRDemoViewController *recieptToCrop=[[OCRDemoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CropTestViewController" bundle:nil];
    [recieptToCrop setImageToCrop:image];
    if ([self.selectedTicketType isEqualToString:@"MAXI QuickPick"]) {
        recieptToCrop.selectedValueOfTicket=50;
        recieptToCrop.drawNumber=self.selectedDrawNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.selectedTicketType isEqualToString:@"JUMBO QuickPick"]) {
        recieptToCrop.selectedValueOfTicket=36;
        recieptToCrop.drawNumber=self.selectedDrawNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.selectedTicketType isEqualToString:@"MEGA QuickPick"]) {
        recieptToCrop.selectedValueOfTicket=24;
        recieptToCrop.drawNumber=self.selectedDrawNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.selectedTicketType isEqualToString:@"REGULAR QuickPick"]) {
        recieptToCrop.selectedValueOfTicket=12;
        recieptToCrop.drawNumber=self.selectedDrawNumber;
    }
    else if ([self.selectedTicketType isEqualToString:@"SUPER QuickPick"]) {
        recieptToCrop.selectedValueOfTicket=18;
        recieptToCrop.drawNumber=self.selectedDrawNumber;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recieptToCrop animated:YES];
    [recieptToCrop release];
    recieptToCrop=nil;
}
```

Comment: This is due to retain release..make sure you are doing correctly

Comment: It gives low memory warning in console before 2 more attempts to capture the image again. :( Strange

Comment: check my answer if it will help you...place code after pushViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not release the picker in the delegate callback, but rather dispatch a block to do it in the next run loop (you can use performSelector after:0 too).

Also use Instruments ObjectAlloc and Leaks to look at what is not getting dealloced.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use instruments?  I never used it before

Comment: This is not a simple one paragraph answer. Search on it in the Apple iOS documentation. Also I think Xcode itself has help on it. From the Product menu, choose Profile, then choose Allocations. Run the app and watch below. Its pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  resize image and then use it.The image clicked from camera is approx. more than 2 mb.Try resizing image captured from camera and then using it.
You need to do:-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);//640*920 or what ever you think appropriate 
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [picker release];
    picker =nil;
}
And now use finalImage instead of image
```